# Printing German umlauts with cc65

Tags: commodore-64, cc65

I want to print German texts with umlauts with a compiled C program on the C64. I'm aware that these characters are not in the charset and that I will have to change the character set.

However, it seems that the umlauts "Ä" and "Ö" are mapped to ASCII characters $76 and $7c, which are printed as the characters "D" and "V", which I want to keep as themselves. Is there a way to change the mapping of umlauts to ASCII in the cc65 compiler?

I've used this program for testing

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void)
{
  printf("äöüÄÖÜß\n"); //mapped to ASCII e4 f6 fc 64 76 7c 7f 0d
}
```

and compiled with `cl65 test.c -o test.prg`.

Comment: Rhetorical question - why didn't they use the codepoints designated for [National Replacement Character Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Replacement_Character_Set)?

Comment: @another-dave to keep the US-ASCII symbols at existing locations? I've added a section about why it may have ended up this way.

Comment: `e4`, `f6`, and `fc` are not ASCII. ASCII is specifically 7-bit. So perhaps because of that there is undefined behaviour?

Comment: @hippietrail These are simply the 8859-1 codes for 'äöü' After all, the compiler does run on a PC and use 8859-1 as default input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your source is most likely in ISO 8859-1 (or -15) encoded (*1), so the compiler has to do code conversion between character literals in your source and the designated target. Without a specifying a target CL65 uses, unlike all other tools, the C64 target by default (*2). As specified in [target.c line 193](https://github.com/cc65/cc65/blob/18afc7c7038280e2443c64e31cf2f0092a484004/src/common/target.c#L193), the C64 Target uses the PETSCII table at [line 113](https://github.com/cc65/cc65/blob/18afc7c7038280e2443c64e31cf2f0092a484004/src/common/target.c#L113), which shows exatly the conversations you noted.

Luckily there's a pragma called [charmap](https://cc65.github.io/doc/cc65.html#ss7.3) to change this. So for example if you want to position the Umlauts at the classic 7 bit [DIN 66003](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_66003) positions simply add the following lines (*3):

```
/* Redefinition of 8859-1 codepoints for Umlauts ("ÄÖÜäöüß") */
/* to ISO-IR-21 aka ISO 646-DE aka DIN 66003                 */
#pragma charmap (0xE4, 0x7B)
#pragma charmap (0xF6, 0x7C)
#pragma charmap (0xFC, 0x7D)
#pragma charmap (0xC4, 0x5B)
#pragma charmap (0xD6, 0x5C)
#pragma charmap (0xDC, 0x5D)
#pragma charmap (0xDF, 0x7E)
```

This is best put in some generic include for all sources (*4).

Also keep in mind that these changes are not global but only effective afterwards and can be overwritten again by a follow up pragma charmap reassigning any of these codes.

---

The default mapping maps the whole 0xC0..0xDF section onto 0x60..0x6F, whichare (mostly) the upper case letters.

At first glace this seems quite strange, really strange, until one realizes that this (0xC1..0xDA) is where the shifted letter keys are returned when reading the keyboard (*5). So in cases of keyboard read this might make some sense.

Still, I have no idea why it's done for character literals. My assumption would be some kind of compatibility situation, or a simple left over from such. So i'd say it was a situation of compatibility vs. support or chars that are not available on a standard PETSCII machine (*6) anyway, where they had to choose which foot to shoot ... and it did hit the Umlauts (*7).

---

*1 - The CC65 suite assumes [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout). [8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) differs by the Euro symbol at 0xA4 and a few other characters.

*2 - Never trust defaults. Using defaults can result in many wasted ours to learn that different programs use different defaults or act on them different. So adding a `-t c64`is always a good idea.

*3 - Just as example, you may of course use any other assignment.

*4 - Don't change any default files, as that would make your sources even less portable.

*5 - the lower case do show up at the standard positions of 0x41..0x5A.

*6 - Ignoring that real PET/CBM machines were sold in national variants, offering additional symbols by replacing certain graphic symbols, thus keeping full ASCII compatibility *and* national characters.

*7 - Which is really sad, as CC65 using ISO-8859-1 source would have allow to support all of them in a standardized fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that the CC65 compiler, like most compilers, would output string literals using whatever sequence of bytes appears in the source file.  If you want to ensure that particular byte values get included in a string, you can use a backslash followed by a three-digit octal number to include any byte value within a string.  While one could use fewer than three octal digits, or else use a hexadecimal syntax, doing things those ways may yield unpleasant results if the next character in a string is interpreted as a digit.  For example, `\015FUNNY" or "\15FUNNY" would yield a carriage return followed by FUNNY, but "\015012345" and "\15012345" would yield a carriage return followed by the digits 012345, and a string with character code 104 (150 octal or 0x68 hex) followed by the digits 12345.

Note that on the Commodore 64, I would recommend drawing direct to screen memory rather than trying to use "printf".  It's going to be faster, and the screen codes are more predictable and easier to work with.

Comment: Some languages/compilers can now handle a source encoding different to the compiled encoding, but usually restricted to just UTF-8/UTF-16 and maybe maybe the OS encoding if it's not one of those. Usually also requires a sigil at one end of the string in the source.